# Will there be a version of Ubuntu Touch for the HTC Sensation?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I would like to ask if you are planning to make versions for HTC Sensation.

It is quite popular phone and has large group of users such as SII.

It is also newer than the Dezire or Dezire S.